# No Spring Cloud Sleuth traces over Kafka

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-sleuth

I am currently running Spring Cloud Edgware.SR2. I am migrating services from RabbitMQ to Kafka, and at this point I don't see any Zipkin traces when I run kafka-console-consumer.sh on the zipkin topic (i.e., `kafka-console-consumer.sh --new-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic zipkin --from-beginning`). As a result, I of course don't see any trace information in the Zipkin UI.

Following are the dependencies I have as part of the producer service:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath></relativePath>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
      <version>Edgware.SR2</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-contract-stub-runner</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-contract-verifier</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka11</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.13.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-integration-java-dsl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-integration-jmx</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.13.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-integration-kafka</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> 
       <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId>
       <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

These are the dependency overrides I had to make after pulling in the `spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka11` dependency per the instructions [at the bottom of the Spring Cloud Stream project page](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/).

I also took a look at the instructions for [Sleuth with Zipkin via RabbitMQ or Kafka](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Edgware.SR2/single/spring-cloud.html#_sleuth_with_zipkin_via_rabbitmq_or_kafka), and I think I have that part correct.

The documentation states `If you want Sleuth over RabbitMQ add the spring-cloud-starter-zipkin and spring-rabbit dependencies.` It specifically mentions `spring-cloud-starter-zipkin` is needed for RabbitMQ, but I added it even though I'm using Kafka since it didn't work without this dependency either.

Any ideas on what I'm missing or have configured incorrectly to capture Sleuth traces and send them to the Zipkin server using Kafka?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you setting the values of dependencies manually? Please use the Edgware.SR2 BOM. You have to add the kafka dependency, ensure that rabbit is not on the classpath. If you have both kafka and rabbit on the classpath you need to set the `spring.zipkin.sender.type=kafka`

UPDATE:

As we describe in the documentation, the Sleuth Stream support is deprecated in Edgware and removed in FInchley. If you've decided to go with the new approach of using native Zipkin messaging support, then you have to use the Zipkin Server with Kafka as described here https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin/tree/master/zipkin-autoconfigure/collector-kafka10 .  Let me copy part of the docs here

---

### Configuration

The following configuration points apply apply when `KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS` or
`zipkin.collector.kafka.bootstrap-servers` is set. They can be configured by setting an environment
variable or by setting a java system property using the `-Dproperty.name=value` command line
argument. Some settings correspond to "New Consumer Configs" in
[Kafka documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#newconsumerconfigs).

Environment Variable | Property | New Consumer Config | Description

`KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS` | `zipkin.collector.kafka.bootstrap-servers` | bootstrap.servers | Comma-separated list of brokers, ex. 127.0.0.1:9092. No default

`KAFKA_GROUP_ID` | `zipkin.collector.kafka.group-id` | group.id | The consumer group this process is consuming on behalf of. Defaults to `zipkin`

`KAFKA_TOPIC` | `zipkin.collector.kafka.topic` | N/A | Comma-separated list of topics that zipkin spans will be consumed from. Defaults to `zipkin`

`KAFKA_STREAMS` | `zipkin.collector.kafka.streams` | N/A | Count of threads consuming the topic. Defaults to `1`

Comment: I am using the Edgware.SR2 BOM in a parent POM. I should have included that, but was shorthanding the dependencies in my child POM. I have updated my original post to avoid that confusion. As far as why I'm setting the dependencies I've listed manually, it's because I am including `spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka11` and as per the instructions at the bottom of https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/ I have to override those specific dependencies.  I have verified I have no references to any of the rabbit jars on the classpath.

Comment: I think it will best if you upload your sample somewhere.

Comment: I will have to create a sample project as I am not authorized to post the code I'm developing for my client. In the mean time, I see a Kafka topic named `sleuth` listed when I list all topics, and I don't see the `zipkin` topic listed. According to [the documentation](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Edgware.SR2/single/spring-cloud.html#_sleuth_with_zipkin_via_rabbitmq_or_kafka), I should be seeing the `zipkin` topic. Is that correct in light of the dependency override instructions listed for `spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka11`?

Comment: Marcin, I had inadvertently removed the `spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin` dependency in a common jar that was there before. Now I can monitor the `zipkin` topic in Kafka and see the Zipkin streams. However, when I start the Zipkin server, I still see that it configures (and I assume, listens on) the `sleuth` topic. How do I configure the Zipkin server to listen on the `zipkin` topic? I have `@EnableZipkinStreamServer` in my main class.

Comment: I've updated the original answer with the answer to your current situation

Comment: Thank you. One more question. Why is streaming support being removed for Zipkin? Is it being removed in favor of using HTTP, which I would think wouldn't be as efficient? Or, is it being removed in favor of using the already supported native Zipkin support for messaging?

Comment: It is it being removed in favor of using the already supported native Zipkin support for messaging.

Comment: Up to this point, I preferred messaging over HTTP when sending data to Zipkin, but I do see in the [documentation](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Edgware.SR2/single/spring-cloud.html#_sending_spans_to_zipkin) that communication to Zipkin over HTTP is asynchronous. I like running Zipkin as a Spring Boot app and the control that approach gives you in terms of being able to save the data off to a JDBC SpanStore, etc. What is your opinion or favored approach between choosing HTTP or message-based integration with Zipkin?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Zipkin project (https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin) is a Spring Boot application. You can configure it a number of ways in exactly the same way as with the deprecated Sleuth Stream server. If you have more questions about Zipkin you can go to their chat https://gitter.im/openzipkin/zipkin .